# Доступ к приватным членам объекта из другого объекта с таким же классом

Tags: ооп, c++11, c++

Возможно ли это? Вот пример :

```
fraction <T> fraction<T>::operator+(const fraction& b) const
{
    fraction newFrac(*this);
    fraction newB(b);
    newFrac.LCD_cast_both(newB);
    newFrac.integer += newB.integer;
    return newFrac;
}
```

будет ли это работать?
Integer - приватный член типа T.

Comment: А попробовать не пробовали? Извините за тавтологию.

Comment: Не будет, у вас отсутствует `return`.

Comment: @dzhioev, нет возможности сейчас)
@VladD, поставил return, спасибо. А если по существу, это ведь не влияет на проблему?

Comment: Ну, отсутствие `return` — UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Будет](https://ideone.com/hT9dRN)*.

Вот [объяснение](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/directly-access-private-in-other-instances.html) из C++ FAQ:

> В идентификаторе `this` нет ничего специального. Доступ даётся или не даётся в зависимости от класса объекта (или ссылки/указателя на него), вне зависимости от идентификатора, представляющего ссылку/указатель/объект.
>
> [...]
>
> Давайте рассмотрим оператор присваивания: `Foo::operator=(Foo const& x)`. Этот оператор должен, скорее всего, изменить данные в объекте-приёмнике, `*this`, исходя из значений данных в объекте-источнике, `x`. В отсутствие правила C++, которое мы обсуждаем, единственная возможность для оператора получить доступ к закрытым полям `x` — это если бы класс `Foo` имел открытый *get*-метод для *каждого закрытого поля*! Это была бы полная хрень.

(перевод мой)

---

*при наличии правильного конструктора копирования у `fraction<T>`, конечно.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду конструктор копирования у типа T? С этим всё нормально.
Меня-то волнует, что integer - приватный член. Вы хотите сказать, что можно так делать?

Comment: Извиняюсь, по ссылке не сходил сначала, спасибо!

Comment: @SIvan32: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @SIvan32: Дополнил релевантной цитатой.